# Option as a singleton collection - real life use cases

Tags: scala, option-type

The title pretty much sums it up. `Option` as a singleton collection can sometimes be confusing, but sometimes it allows for an interesting application. I have one example on top of my head, and would like to learn more of such examples.

My only example is running `for` comprehension on the `Option[List[T]]`. We can do the following:

```
val v = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
for {
  list <- v.toList
  elem <- list
} yield elem + 1
```

Without having `Option.toList`, it wouldn't be possible to stay in the same `for` comprehension, and I'd be forced to write something like this:

```
for {
  list <- v
} yield for {
  elem <- list
} yield elem + 1
```

The first example is cleaner, and it's an advantage of `Option` being a collection. Of course, the result type will be different in these 2 examples, but let's assume it doesn't matter for the sake of discussion.

Any other examples? I'd especially like to concentrate on collection-like usage, and not usage of `Option`'s monadic properties - those are pretty much obvious. In other words, `map` and `flatMap` functions are out of scope of this question. They're definitely very useful, just coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I find that working with `Option[T]` as a collection's main benefit is that you get to use operations defined on a collection, such as `map`, `flatmap`, `filter`, `foreach` etc. This makes it easier to do operations on a given option, instead of using pattern matching or checking `Option[T].isDefined` to see if a value exists.

For example, let's take the user repository example from [Daniel Westheide blog post about `Option[T]`](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html):

Say you have a `UserRepository` object which returns users based on their ID. The user may or may not exist, hence it returns an `Option[Person]`. Now let's say we want to search a person by id and then filter their age. We can do:

```
val age: Some[Int] = UserRepository.findById(1).map(_.age)
```

Now let's say that a `Person` also has a `gender` property of type `Option[String]`. If you wanted to extract that out, you could use `map`:

```
val gender: Option[Option[String]] = UserRepository.findById(1).map(_.gender)
```

But working with nested options isn't too convenient. For that, you have `flatMap`:

```
val gender: Option[String] = UserRepository.findById(1).flatMap(_.gender)
```

And if we want to print out the gender if it exists, we can use `foreach`:

```
gender.foreach(println)
```

You'll find yourself working with scala types that have nested `Option[T]` fields defined and it's really handy to have collection like methods which help you remove out boilerplate and noise for extracting the actual value out of the operation.

A more real life use case I just encountered the other day was working with the awscala SDK, where I wanted to retrieve an object from S3 storage:

```
val bucket: Option[Bucket] = s3.bucket(amazonConfig.bucketName)
val result: Option[S3Object] = bucket.flatMap(_.get(amazonConfig.offsetKey))
result.flatMap(s3Object => 
    Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.content).mkString.decodeOption[Array[KafkaOffset]])
```

So what happens here is that you query the S3 service for a bucket, which may or may not exist. Then, you want to extract an `S3Object` out of it which actually contains the data, but the API itself returns an `Option[S3Object]`, so it's handy to use `flatMap` to flat out get an `Option[S3Object]` instead of `Option[Option[S3Object]]`. Finally, I want to deserialize the `S3Object` which actually contains a JSON, and using the Argonaut library, it returns an `Option[MyObject]`, so then again using `flatMap` to the rescue of extracting the inner option type.

### Edit:

As you pointed out, `map` and `flatMap` belong to the monadic property of `Option[T]`. I've written a [blog post](http://asyncified.io/2016/04/16/reducing-two-options-in-scala/) describing the reduction of two options where the final solution was:

```
def reduce[T](a: Option[T], b: Option[T], f: (T, T) => T): Option[T] = {
  (a ++ b).reduceLeftOption(f)
}
```

Which takes advantage of the [`++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@++[B](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):Option[B]) operator defined on any collection which is also specifically defined on `Option[T]`, being a collection.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Please see the addendum to my question: `map` and `flatMap` are coming from the monadic nature of the `Option`, so they're out of scope. Collection-like usage is really the focus.

Comment: @Haspemulator You're right. I gave the use cases for `map` and `flatMap` as they were already in the post. But there are plenty of other operations you can apply such as `filter`, `foldLeft`, `groupBy`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a look at [the corresponding chapter](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) of The Neophyte's Guide to Scala.
In my experience, most useful use-cases of Option-as-collection are to filter an option and to make flatMap that implicitly filters None values.