# Scala - compare two Option[Seq[String]]

Tags: scala, collections

I am new to the Scala language - I seem to have a problem finding the right syntax for sorting and comparing two Option[Seq[String]]. The two should be equals irrespective of contents order. The last line in this test fails. I hope this code sufficiently documents the question.

```
  package seqtest

import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpec}

class SortCollectionsTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "Different seq order" should "not affect equality" in {

    val seqAB1 = Seq("A","B")
    val seqAB2 = Seq("A","B")
    // two different sequences are equal
    assert(seqAB1 == seqAB2)

    val seqBA1 = Seq("B","A")
    // two different sequences are not equal if different order
    assert(seqAB1 != seqBA1)

    // but is possible to convert sequence to list and sort
    assert(seqAB1.toList.sorted == seqBA1.toList.sorted)


    // now do the same thing with Option

    val someSeqAB1 = Some(Seq("A","B"))
    val someSeqAB2 = Some(Seq("A","B"))
    // two different option sequences are equal
    assert(someSeqAB1 == someSeqAB2)

    val someSeqBA = Some(Seq("B","A"))
    // two different optional sequences are not equal if different order
    assert(someSeqAB1 != someSeqBA)

    // Option can be converted into list (unsorted)
    assert(someSeqAB1.toList != someSeqBA.toList)

    // problem
    // two different optional sequences cannot be sorted
    // compilation error
    // Error:(42, 30) No implicit Ordering defined for Seq[String].
    // Error:(42, 30) not enough arguments for method sorted: (implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[Seq[String]])List[Seq[String]].
    // Unspecified value parameter ord.
    assert(someSeqAB1.toList.sorted == someSeqBA.toList.sorted)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I also seem to have a problem with the StackOverflow code formatting. ..

Comment: When you do `someSeqAB1.toList` you are getting a `List[Seq[String]]`. You are getting an error when trying to sort this list because a `Seq[String]` has no implicit ordering defined.

Comment: `someSeqAB1.toList` compiles because `Option` is `Iterable`, caused by this implicit conversion: `scala.Option#option2Iterable`. `Option.toList` gives you a singleton `List` when `Option.isDefined`, or empty list otherwise. Welcome to Scala.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/36933813/371804

Comment: Having worked through the different conversions, I now have the following which compiles and works

`assert(someSeqAB1.getOrElse(Seq("")).toList.sorted == someSeqBA.getOrElse(Seq("")).toList.sorted)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the much easier solution would be to map the options:

```
assert(someSeqAB1.map{ _.sorted } == someSeqBA.map{ _.sorted })
```

Btw, to the sorted version the assertion is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Matchers` i'd suggest to do something like this:

```
someSeqAB1 should not be empty
someSeqBA should not be empty
someSeqAB1.get should contain theSameElementsAs someSeqBA.get
```

Comment: Yup, and as you can see, I'm new to scalatest as well : )